# Show that the even and odd terms of the sequence described by $x_1=\frac{1}{3}, x_{n+1}=\frac{{x_n}^2+1}{5x_n}$ are monotonic and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $$x_1=\dfrac{1}{3}, x_{n+1}=\dfrac{{x_n}^2+1}{5x_n}.$$ Show that the even terms are monotone decreasing and bounded and the odd terms are monotone increasing and bounded.

> $\textbf{My Attempt:}$
>   I first showed that $x_1<x_3$, then assumed for some positive integer $k$ that $x_{2k-1}<x_{2k+1}$. From there I attempted show that $0<x_{2k+1}-x_{2k-1}$ implies $0<x_{2k+3}-x_{2k+1}$, by substituting in $$x_{2k+3}=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{(x_{2k+1})^2+1}{5x_{2k+1}}\right)^2+1}{5\left(\dfrac{(x_{2k+1})^2+1}{5x_{2k+1}}\right)},$$ and $$x_{2k+1}=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{(x_{2k-1})^2+1}{5x_{2k-1}}\right)^2+1}{5\left(\dfrac{(x_{2k-1})^2+1}{5x_{2k-1}}\right)}.$$
>   However, the algebra became very messy, so I think there may be a better approach that I've missed. I know the sequences of even and odd terms should both be bounded by $\frac 1 2$. I again tried to show this using induction, but ran into trouble when trying to show that $x_{2k+1}\leq \frac 1 2 \implies x_{2k+3}\leq \frac 1 2$.

Any suggestions/hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried considering $g = f\circ f$, where $f(x) = \frac{x^2+1}{5x}$; and tried to show that $g'(x) > 0$? This is also messy, though!

Answer (score 1):

As an approach, first look for a fixed point, and see how the iterates behave with respect to that point. Then show that the iterates remain within some ball around the fixed points, and then show that within this ball (or a smaller one) that the iterates converge.

Thanks to @user81146 who caught a major error in a previous proof.

A little computation shows $x_2 = \frac{2}{3}$ and $x_3 = \frac{13}{30}$.

Note that $f(x)-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{x-2}{5x} ( x -\frac{1}{2})$, and so $|f(x)-\frac{1}{2}| \le |\frac{x-2}{5x} | | x -\frac{1}{2}|$, that is,
$|x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2} | \le |\frac{x_n-2}{5x_n} | | x_n -\frac{1}{2}|$.

Now note that $|\frac{x-2}{5x} | \le $ **iff** $x \ge \frac{1}{3}$ (we are only concerned with $x \ge 0$ here).
Hence if $x_n \ge \frac{1}{3}$, then $|x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2} | \le  | x_n -\frac{1}{2}|$. To ensure that $x_n \ge \frac{1}{3}$ for all $n$, we need to have $|x_1-\frac{1}{2}| \le \frac{1}{6}$. Since $x_1 = \frac{1}{3}$, we see that this is satisfied, hence the sequence is bounded, and in particular, the distance from $\frac{1}{2}$ is non-increasing.

If we examine $\phi(x) = |\frac{x-2}{5x} |$ on $[\frac{1}{3},2]$, we see that $\phi(\frac{1}{3}) = 1$ and it is strictly decreasing. Since $x_3 > \frac{1}{3}$, we have $x_n \ge x_3 > \frac{1}{3}$ for all $n \ge 3$, and hence $\phi(x_n) \le \phi(x_3) <1$, and the above shows $|x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2} | \le  \phi(x_3)| x_n -\frac{1}{2}|$ for all $n \ge 3$. In particular, we see that $x_n \to \frac{1}{2}$.

Note that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,1)$ and $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$. Hence if $x_n >\frac{1}{2}$ then $x_{n+1}=f(x_n) < \frac{1}{2}$ and similarly,
if $x_n <\frac{1}{2}$, then $x_{n+1}=f(x_n) > \frac{1}{2}$.
Hence the odd terms satisfy $x_n < \frac{1}{2}$ and the even terms satisfy $x_n >\frac{1}{2}$. (This also shows that $x_n \neq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$.)

Since we have $|x_{n+2}-\frac{1}{2}| \le \phi(x_3) |x_{n}-\frac{1}{2}|$ for $n \ge 3$, we see that
the odd terms are increasing and the even terms are decreasing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the function is strictly decreasing only on the interval $(0,1)$. I think this approach should still work but it would require us to first show that each term is in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @user81146: Good observation, thanks. I have shown that $|x_n-\frac{1}{2}| \le \frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: @user81146: Turned out that switching the order of the proof was all that was needed (and to correct my statement about where $f$ is decreasing). Thanks!

Comment: Another subtle bug: $f(x)-\frac 1 2 = \frac{x-2}{5x}(x-\frac 1 2)$, which means $|x_{n+1}|\leq |x_n-\frac 1 2|$ is not necessarily true.

Comment: @user81146:Not so subtle.

Comment: @user81146: I fixed the problem, but the proof is much more delicate than before.

Answer (score 0):

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{5} ( \frac{x_n}{1} + \frac{1}{x_n})$$

Let $C = 2/5,\ D=\frac{1}{5}(C+\frac{1}{C})$

So $x_1=1/3 < D$, $C<x_2 =(3+1/3)/5=2/3<1$, $x_1 < x_3 =13/30<D$ so that $$
C<x_4 <x_2,
$$

which also implies $$ D>x_5> x_3. $$

(1) With this observation, we use induction on odd term $$D>x_{2n+3} > x_{2n+1}$$

$k=3$-case is proved. If $k=2n-1$ is satisfied, that is, $x_{2n-1}<x_{2n+1}<D$, so $$(A)\ x_{2n}=\frac{1}{5} (\frac{1}{x_{2n-1}} + x_{2n-1}) > x_{2n+2} = \frac{1}{5} (\frac{1}{x_{2n+1}} + x_{2n+1}) >C
$$ So continually we have $$x_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{5} (\frac{1}{x_{2n}} + x_{2n}) < x_{2n+3} = \frac{1}{5} (\frac{1}{x_{2n+2}} + x_{2n+2}) < D.$$

(2) So we can conclude from odd term's increasing and bound 
that even term is decreasing and bounded (See (A)).

Comment: Note that even term's decreasing implies odd term's increasing. That is, stop of decreasing implies the stop of increasing.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is rather nice.

Comment: I don't think $(A)$ follows immediately from our assumption that $x_{2n-1}<x_{2n+1}$. I see that $x_{2n-1}<x_{2n+1}\implies \frac{1}{x_{2n-1}}>\frac{1}{x_{2n+1}}$. However, I don't think it follows immediately that $\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{x_{2n-1}}+x_{2n-1}\right)>\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{x_{2n+1}}+x_{2n-1}\right)$.

Comment: For example, say $x_{2n-1}=\frac 1 2$ and $x_{2n+1}=\frac 1 4$, then $\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{x_{2n-1}}+x_{2n-1}\right)=\frac{3}{10}\not>\frac{17}{20} =\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}.{x_{2n+1}}+x_{2n-1}\right)$

Comment: In your example $x_{2n-1} >x_{2n+1}$ So this is the case we donot consider. If $a=x_{2n-1} <b=x_{2n+1} <1$ then $(1/a+a)-(1/b+b) =\frac{b-a}{ab} + (a-b)=(b-a)(1/(ab)-1) > 0$ since $1/(ab) > 1$.

Comment: My mistake. My example should have set $x_{2n-1}=2$ and $x_{2n+1}=4$. So the inductive step also relies on the fact that $x_{2n-1}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ are both less than 1. For the inductive argument in (1) to go through I think you need to also show that $x_{2n}$, $x_{2n+2}$, and $x_{2n+3}$ are all less than 1. In (3) and (4), you show that the even and odd terms are bounded, but in doing so you use the fact that they are decreasing and increasing respectively, which we cannot say we know until we show that $x_{2n}$, $x_{2n+2}$, and $x_{2n+3}$ are all less than 1.